# How can I update value in object with node.js and sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to update values (missions.status and missions.success) in the object,
but I don't know how to approach it.

```js
"missions": {
   "missions": [
      {
       "week": 1,
       "status": "",
       "mission": "do something",
       "success": ""
      }
    ]
 }
```

I tried to like this.

```js
//success.js

router.put('/:id/result', async (req, res, next) => {
  const status = req.body.missions.missions[0].status;
  const success = req.body.missions.missions[0].success;
  try {
    const result = await models.User.findOne({
      attribute: ['missions'],
      where: {
        id: req.params.id,
      },
    });

    const data = {
      result: result,
    };
    let originalData = data.result.dataValues.missions.missions[0];
    let weekdata = { status: status, success: success };
    let resultData = Object.assign(originalData, weekdata);

    res.send({
      data: resultData,
      message: 'good status changed',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }
});
```

It is req.body and response, looks like it works, but doesn't update in databases. I don't know how to save that.

```js
//req.body
{
"missions": {
    "missions":[
  {
   "status": "no",
   "success":"success"
  }
   ]
    }
  }


// res.send
{
  "data": {
      "week": 1,
      "status": "no",
      "mission": "do something",
      "success": "success"
  },
  "message": "good status changed"
}
```

Comment: You didn't post the problem because that code should do what you desired as an output.

Comment: @Ele I wrote more about my problem. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call **update** for your model so that's why you'll get no changes in a DB.
Try this:

```
await models.User.update(weekdata, {
      where: {
        id: req.params.id,
      },
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still doesn't work and shows error.

`AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter at Function`

Comment: can you edit your post to reflect changes with `update` call?